# Multiple Intents in DialogFlow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I want to have the user respond with a longish response, like talk about their education and family background. In this, I would like to identify multiple intents and then go back to the user with multiple questions (one by one) as a follow-on to the intents detected. Can I do this in DialogFlow CX and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your desired use case is currently not feasible in Dialogflow CX. By default, Dialogflow matches a user query to only one intent route. Intents are [matched](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/intent#match) based on the [confidence](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.Match) value in the detectIntent Response’s [queryResult.match](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.Match) field.

Moreover, the maximum detect intent text input length is 256 characters. If you are using an [integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration), the integration platform may have a smaller limit. However, you can use the sys.long-utterance [built-in event](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event-built-in) to handle user queries that exceed the 256-character limit. Note that the long user query will still only get matched to only one intent route.

If you want to ask the user multiple questions, you can design your agent to have a conversation flow that asks the user one question at a time. You can utilize [State Handlers](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler) to control the conversation flow. You may refer to the [Voice agent design](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/voice-agent-design) documentation for best practices for designing your agent.

Answer (score 0):

You could do several intents with no response that has several follow up intents with your questions, u are going to need to change the number of context to match the amount of intents that you are going to use.

Comment: Thanks Luiz. I am afraid, it was not super clear to me. Can I read-up somewhere or perhaps a video that may help? I have gone thru all DialogflowCX on YT and they are not very helpful in this case unfortunately.